# ¿Cómo puedo leer la segunda línea de un archivo.txt en Pyhton?

Tags: python

Estoy realizando una práctica donde me pide que lea sólo la segunda línea que contiene un archivo.txt, no logro saber como puedo leer específicamente la segunda línea. Sólo puedo leer la primera

Answer (score 4):

Aunque puedes usar `readlines()` para leer todas las líneas y quedarte solo con la segunda, esto es en general ineficiente. Imagina que el archivo tiene millones de líneas. Leerlo completo tardaría mucho y además estarías usando gigas de memoria RAM para mantener la lista con todas las líneas leídas, cuando en realidad sólo necesitas leer las dos primeras (y ni siquiera necesitas mantener ambas en memoria, basta con la segunda).

La siguiente solución itera en un bucle hasta llegar a la línea que te interesa y después sale del bucle. De ese modo se evita leer el resto del fichero. Además en cada iteración se guarda solo la línea que toca, descartando las anteriores, con lo que se consume menos memoria.

```
fichero = open("nombre-del-fichero")

for numero, linea in enumerate(fichero):
   if numero == 1:  # Segunda línea, pues la primera sería la numero 0
      break
fichero.close()
print(linea)
```

La solución anterior es muy genérica pues cambiando el 1 por otro número puedes leer cualquier otra línea. Es necesario, eso sí, pasar por todas las líneas anteriores debido a la naturaleza secuencial de los ficheros, pero al menos no se van almacenando en una lista.

Para el caso particular de leer sólo la segunda línea puedes usar este otro truco:

```
fichero = open("nombre-del-fichero")
linea = next(fichero)
linea = next(fichero)
fichero.close()
print(linea)
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método readlines()

```
with open(<file_name>) as f:
    lineas = f.readlines()
    # imprimes la línea que te interesa, ej la primera -> lineas[0]
```

Suerte !

Answer (score 0):

El archivo.txt tiene dos lineas:

```
hola
mundo

#leer archivo
archivo = open('archivo.txt', 'r') 
#leer lineas del archivo
lineas = archivo.readlines()
#Imprimir segunda linea
print(lineas[1])
#Salida
>> mundo
```

Si quieres imprimir la linea 1 sería:

```
print(lineas[0])
```

Imprimir todas las lineas:

```
for line in lineas: 
    print(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
print(open("inter.txt", "r").readlines()[1])
```

`readlines` retorna una lista donde cada elemento es una línea del archivo. Con `[1]` obtenemos el segundo elemento de la lista.